# Why isn’t my water simulation transparent?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, transparency, fluid-simulation, rigid-body-simulation

I tried to do a product commercial, where the product falls into water and followed a tutorial. I think I did every step right. I even used the same HDRI.

So does someone have an idea why my water simulation keeps just showing me the reflections of the HDRI in the Glas BSDF and not the can like water should do?

[image]
(what it should look like in rendered view)

[image]
(What my water simulation in rendered view looks like)

Comment: The tutorial uses _Cycles_, not _Eevee_ for rendering like you do. In _Eevee_, transmissive materials like glass do not work out-of-the-box, you have to switch the _Blend Mode_ from _Opaque_ to either _Alpha Hashed_ or _Alpha Blend_ under _Material Properties_ > _Settings_. And most probably you need to enable _Screen Space Refraction_ there too and _Screen Space Reflections_ in the _Render Properties_. By the way, no need to add "(blender)" in the title, this site is only about Blender issues ;)

Comment: Thank u so much!! I tried to solve that problem for 2 days .       Also after using cycles with the alpha blend material setting on, it worked much better. But now the water is colored blue. Is there a setting where can change that, so it looks completely dark like in the tutorial?

Comment: _Alpha Blend_ in _Cycles_? That shouldn't do anything for the rendered view... maybe the _Material Preview_ (this uses _Eevee_). Well, about the look of the material: is there no material setup in the tutorial? If not, I would really recommend you watch tutorials on how to create materials - or open another question here, because on this site we prefer to have one problem per question.